# What's the correct way to chain pipes within pipes in Node?

Tags: node.js, stream

I have a function that may return one or more streams piped, back to a main function that is chaining streams together:

```
function streamBuilder(){
     const csvStream = require('fast-csv').createWriteStream();
     const fsStream = fs.createWriteStream('file.csv');
     return csvStream.pipe(fsStream);
}

const dbStream = db.collection('huge').find();
const streams = streamBuilder();
dbStream.pipe(streams);
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work.

The result is that the CSV stream `csvStream.transform()` is apparently never called, only the file write stream `fileStream.transform()`, which errors with a invalid chunk argument.

If I do this instead, it works:

```
function streamBuilder(){
     const csvStream = require('fast-csv').createWriteStream();
     const fsStream = fs.createWriteStream('file.csv');
     return csvStream.on('data', chunk => fsStream.write(chunk));
}
```

But if doesn't feel right... there must be a way to chain stream pipes when they are nested (ie. `streamA.pipe(streamB.pipe(streamC))`). Is there a way I can just chain them without `.on('data'...)` and without sending input streams as arguments into the `streamBuilder()` function?